# View the complete list of a taxonomy in the navigation menu

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, list

I have a taxonomy called "country" and I need to visualize it as a list of categories can someone help me?

```
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/country/argentina/">Argentina</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/country/australia/">Australia </a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/country/canada/">Canada</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/country/china/">China</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/country/france/">France</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/country/germany/">Germany</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/country/india/">India</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/country/italy/">Italy</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/country/spain/">Spain</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/country/south-korea/">Korea</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/country/uk/">United Kingdom</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/country/usa/">USA</a></li>
```

Comment: Hi Vincenzo! So you want to create output like this from your taxonomy? Do you want to write code to do this and add it to your theme? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result using following code:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'country',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
) );

if ( !empty($terms) ) :
    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach( $terms as $country ) {
        $output.= '<li><a href="'.get_term_link( $country->term_id ).'">'. esc_attr( $country->name ) .'</a></li>';
    }
    $output.='</ul>';
    echo $output;
endif;
```

Here I'm using `get_terms()` to get all item of `country` taxonomy. The checking if there is any item in the list. If yes then I'm looping through them and returning as desired link. `get_term_link()` is being used to get the term url by using term id.

Comment: is there a way to convert the code into function so i can paste it into the functions.php file and use only the function?

Comment: just wrap the code as a function. like `function list_country(){ here the code above }`

Comment: thanks! works fine!